# What is the difference between VP9 and ​WebM?

Tags: ffmpeg, file-formats

The [ffmpeg manual](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/VP9) states that:

> libvpx-vp9 is the VP9 video encoder for ​WebM, an open, royalty-free media file format.

What is the difference between the VP9 and WebM?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

VP9 is a **video format**. Another example is H.264.

WebM is a **container format** that VP9 goes into. It is equivalent to the MP4 container format for the H.264 video format.

libvpx is a **video encoder** (or **codec**) which outputs the VP8 or VP9 video formats. Another encoder example is x264 which outputs the H.264 video format.

Comment: Note that codec can typically be put in multiple containers, and a container can typically accept multiple codecs.

Comment: Since I don't do video work frequently, I always forget this important distinction. I wish I had a cheat-sheet showing what goes with what.

Comment: @LonnieBest [Comparison of video container formats](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_video_container_formats) might be helpful.